# Scala compilation error on nested pattern matching

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching

I am using Scala 2.10.5 and Spark 1.6.0.

My code is:

```
  def computeContribs(tuples : RDD[(Int,List[Int])], ranks : RDD[(Int, Double)] ) : RDD[(Int, Double)] = {
    val x = tuples.map{case(numpage,list)=>(numpage,(list,1.0/list.size))}
    val joined = x.join(ranks)
    val contribs = joined.flatMap{case(numPage,(pageList,size), rank) => pageList.map( y:Int=>(y,size) )}
    contribs.reduceByKey(_+_)
  }
```

The compilation error I get is:

```
[error] C:\Users\vital\Documents\spazi_lavoro\spark-examples\src\main\scala\pagerank\PageRankSpark.scala:11: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : (T1, T2, T3)
[error]  required: (Int, ((List[Int], Double), Double))
[error]     val contribs = joined.flatMap{case(numPage,(pageList,size), rank) => pageList.map( y:Int=>(y,size) )}
[error]

                                   ^
```

How can I make my code compile?

Comment: Change your contribs RDD to, 
val contribs = joined.flatMap{case(numPage,((pageList,size), rank)) => pageList.map(y => (y , size) )}

Comment: @vindev thank you! If you make it a solution, I will accept it

Comment: Great !!! just posted the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `joined` `RDD` is of the type `RDD[(Int, ((List[Int], Double), Double))]` so while applying `flatmap` to this `RDD` you need `Case Class` of of the same type i.e. `(numPage,((pageList,size), rank))` not `(numPage,(pageList,size), rank)`. Also you don't need to specify type (`Int`) in your `map` function. You can change your contribs RDD to following.

```
val contribs: RDD[(Int, Double)] = 
    joined.flatMap{case (numPage,((pageList,size), rank)) => 
    pageList.map(y => (y , size) )}
```